# creating all permutations of a list with a limited range in Scala

Tags: list, scala, permutation, seq

I am trying to create a sequence of n-element lists comprising all permutations for a given range. Would like to parameterize both the number of elements and range. Example:

Length: 4, Range: [0, 3]

`Seq(List(0, 0, 0, 0), List(0, 0, 0, 1), ..., List(3, 3, 3, 3), ..., List(1, 0, 0, 0))`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, when you were _trying_ to do it, what were the problems you ran into?

Comment: Simply said, I couldn't manipulate the permutation function to generate the lists as shown.

Comment: I tried what jwvh suggested, and the following:
  val test = List(1,2,3).toSet[Int].subsets.map(_.toList).toList
  val test = List.range(0, 2).toList.transpose
  val test = for {
    v <- List.range(0, 3)
    s <- List.range(1, 6)
  } yield (v, s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you there.

```
List.fill(4)(0 to 3).flatten.combinations(4).flatMap(_.permutations)
```

It returns an `Iterator` that can be cast to `Seq`, `List`, `Vector`, whatever.

You need **n** copies of the range so that `combinations()` will allow **n** repetitions of each number within the range.

---

**Explanation**

`combinations` is all about ignoring the order of the elements, so (0,1) is considered the same as (1,0) and only one of them will be presented.  You also have to tell it the size of the sub-groups.

`permutations` is all about reordering the given elements, so (2,2) has only one permutation, itself, while (0,0,1) has 3: (0,0,1) (0,1,0) (1,0,0)

After `combinations` has created the initial groupings of the elements, each one is fed to `permutations` to get all possible re-orderings.

Comment: It does not create all possible combinations--sequence matters. For instance, nothing like (3, 0, 1, 0) is created. Thoughts?

Comment: @tmesis, oops.  Updated. The result won't be in an obvious order, but it should be complete.

Comment: That is an elegant solution. I tried adding `permutations` to your initial response but it yielded a wild result. Would you please explain why your fix worked but my attempt produced excessive output?